# Kendo UI Scheduler: Hide week-view Time Headers (MVC)

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-scheduler

I'm trying to find a way to remove the time headers from the kendo scheduler. I've come across a few ways to do it via css, but they tend to leave the scheduler looking a bit "off".

I found some answers in the kendo docs detailing how to do it out of the box with a [javascript implementation](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/scheduling/scheduler/how-to/hide-time-header), but I'm looking for MVC which I can't seem to find any mention of. I've tried and tried to figure out how to do this, but I can't seem to find the appropriate attributes to set.

Answer (score 0):

The kendo MVC wrappers are effectively ASPX/Razor helper functions that generate a javascript implementation. So assuming the javascript solution in the link you provide contains the solution you need, it should be possible to replicate it using the MVC syntax.

Looking at telerik's solution, they manipulate the DOM with javascript in the dataBinding event for Ungrouped and in dataBound for Grouped. You can specify handlers for these events when declaring the scheduler with MVC syntax:

```
.Events(e => {
    e.DataBound("scheduler_dataBound");
    e.DataBinding("scheduler_dataBinding");
})
```

...and then include the implementation of these functions on the page separately (code lifted from the telerik solution):

```
<script>
    function scheduler_dataBound(e) {
        var tables = $(".k-scheduler-times .k-scheduler-table");
        //Required: remove only last table in dataBound when grouped
        tables = tables.last();
        var rows = tables.find("tr");
        rows.each(function() {
          $(this).children("th:last").hide();
    }

    function scheduler_dataBinding(e) {
        var view = this.view();
        view.times.hide();
        view.timesHeader.hide();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: This doesn't quite work the way I want. I set the dataBinding event function, but the time headers are still visible while the data is loading (I'm loading via ajax). Once the data loads, it removed the time headers, but leaves the column they were in. So from a user perspective I've got spontaneously disappearing time headers and a blank white column at the far left side.

Answer (score 0):

//for hiding time header

$('#schedulerID').find('.k-scheduler-header-wrap').closest('tr').hide()

//for hiding date header

$(".k-scheduler-layout tr:first .k-scheduler-table").find("tr:eq(0)").hide()

Comment: Both of these only remove the date headers at the top of the scheduler, and the first one causes formatting issues for the rest of the scheduler cells.

Comment: It works fine but can solve with css if any further issues